# Including a file over a HTTPS connection

Tags: php

Firstly, let me show you my code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$id = 123456;
include("https://secure.example.com/log.php");
?>
```

**log.php**

```
<?php
echo $id;
?>
```

This simple code should, in theory, display **123456** on `index.php`, correct? However, I get nothing. I can only assume it's because I'm trying to include a file over a https connection, but is this actually the case? `index.php` is NOT on the secure server.

I have the following setting turned on in `php.ini`:

```
allow_url_include = 1
allow_url_fopen   = 1
```

Checking wrappers with the following code:

```
var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());
```

Gives me an array showing `https`:

```
array(12) {
    [0]=> string(5) "https"
    [1]=> string(4) "ftps"
    [2]=> string(13) "compress.zlib"
    [3]=> string(14) "compress.bzip2"
    [4]=> string(3) "php"
    [5]=> string(4) "file"
    [6]=> string(4) "glob"
    [7]=> string(4) "data"
    [8]=> string(4) "http"
    [9]=> string(3) "ftp"
    [10]=> string(4) "phar"
    [11]=> string(3) "zip"
}
```

Comment: I hope you have a really good reason for even trying this! That said, what is the state of the SSL certificate on your secure server - is it a proper one or self signed?

Comment: Even if this is possible it is one of the worst ideas ever conceived.

Comment: You really should not do this with include, include is used for including local files to your php scripts. What you are trying to do is open HTTPS connection and download the contents of the web page, you should use file_get_contents() OR curl, I don't remember if file_get_contents supports HTTPS.

Comment: My reasoning? The code I want to include just happens to be residing on our secure server. The pages I need it included on will not be. It has a valid, proper SSL Certificate. I can see why including the other way around, non-secure items on a secure page, could be a problem, but not this way around.

Comment: If you just want the code, I think there are some devops tools and commands that are better than PHP, for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync
If you want the code to be interpreted on the secure server and then you want an answer back, then you should implement an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual, always read [the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

If the target server interprets the target file as PHP code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request string as used with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script.

Comment: Which means he needs to use something like: `<?php echo '<'.'?php'
echo $id;
?'.'>';`

Comment: Or send the $id as parameter through GET

Answer (score 2):

index.php

```
<?php
$id = 123456;
include("https://secure.example.com/log.php");
?>
```

Either log.**txt** or log.**php** using `<?php echo '<'.'?php' echo $id; ?'.'>';` like shown by *scragar*.

```
<?php
echo $id;
?>
```

The big problem here is, that you **expose** the sourecode of the file on https server - at least partially. You need to do this to be able to parse its contents remotely before the residing server does.

What I suggest to do is a complete different approach.

Connect to the https server [using SSH](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php). This is a common and secure way to get data from a different server properly. No risky configuration, no sourcecode exposed to the public.

Another alternative way is to implement a SOAP/REST or simple RPC, like you request the https server and it returns the result in json, which isn't risky, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on some error reporting to see what actually happens:

```
<?php
    error_reporting (E_ALL);
    ini_set ("display_errors", 1);

    $id = 123456;
    include("https://secure.example.com/log.php");
?>
```

**EDIT:** Yes, as I can see now, the real problem probably is that you are not including the source of the log.php but the output of it. So there may be no errors to report.

Comment: This still won't help, his log.php is going to output an empty string and raise a notice, he'll include the file and do nothing with it.

Comment: At least he will see this notice.

Comment: @Cthulhu probably not, there's nothing here to turn notices on in his other file accessed via http, so if it defaults to not displaying warnings like most servers are he still won't see anything at all.